# High CPU usage caused by process "System"

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I'm programming a WPF application. I used `BitmapCache` in some windows, like this:

```
CacheMode = new BitmapCache() {
            EnableClearType = false,
            RenderAtScale = 2,
            SnapsToDevicePixels = false; }
```

Then:

1. Run my appliction, cpu usage is normal.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, show Task Manager, the process named "System" shows high CPU usage.

Process Explorer shows the problem that it is caused by these 2 threads:

> ntoskrnl.exe!WheaAttemptPhysicalPageOffline+0x350
>   dxgmms1.sys!VidMmInterface+0x26500

I used Intel HD Graphics.

Is this a bug of WPF, direct or graphic driver? Does anybody know?

Comment: High for how long? How high? Why should it be a bug?

Comment: It will hold several minutes, and WPF screen will be freezed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "System" process is a fake process that shows statistics for the Windows code that runs in ring 0.  Device drivers live there, for example.  Dxgmms1.sys is the memory manager for DirectX.  WPF uses DirectX to render graphics.  Bitmaps can use a lot of memory.

Seeing a WPF app that uses bitmaps spending a lot of cpu time in a DirectX related device driver is therefore no great mystery.  Intel HD Graphics is a bottom-of-the-barrel cheap implementation of a graphics accelerator.  Spending fifty bucks on an AMD or NVidea video card would be a likely quick fix.  Not asking WPF to scale the bitmap or limiting the rate at which it needs to be rendered because the visual tree was invalidated could well be another quick fix.

Comment: Yes, this issue doesn't happen in NVidea video card.

Comment: And i found, it also  doesn't happen when i show a single window and set bitmapcahce. But when i showed multiple windows, it also  doesn't happen if i set bitmapCache in first showed window. It happened if i set bitmapCache in my second showed window. It's very curious.